# Не удается создать UWP приложение

Tags: visual-studio

Добрый день. Я пытаюсь создать UWP приложение, но возникает ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем дело? Я использую Visual studio community 2015 Update 3. Уже несколько раз пытался переустановить студию не помогло. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась переустановкой студии на англоязычную локализацию.

Comment: Если это баг локализации студии - стоит запостить его в Microsoft connect.